# How to make an object move independently but also with a parent object?

Tags: animation

I am trying to make an animation of a briefcase lock where the lock spins to a code then the briefcase opens. How do I make the cylinder locks spin on their own but then move with the top of the briefcase when it opens? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: what about parenting all of them to the top?

Comment: Yup... that's what parenting _is_. Barring any other constraints, The child is free to move in the space defined by the parent object's local axes. If the parent is transformed, the child transforms along with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should Shift+Click on all your cylinders first and then on the top of the briefcase lastly to make it the active object.
Then press P to Parent all the objects you selected to the last one you clicked (the top of the briefcase). 
This will let you move the briefcase without affecting the individual transformations.

Comment: Also don't be afraid to add additional Empties and use them as parents. In my last animation, I ended up with mesh components parented to an empty which acted as a "group" which was parented to another Empty that allowed extreme control of the rotational pivot point that was in turn parented to a Mesh that already had some location animation defined.